# Escape Character Needed for Password

Tags: powershell, escaping

This script works great to accept some read-host prompts and create a website with an app pool tied to it. The password prompt works except our most common password is !$Pass!123!! and it will not allow me to receive it as input. How do you allow these characters to be used?

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
```

```
# Get Web Site Variables
$WebSite = Read-Host -Prompt "DNS name for Web Site"
$AppPoolName = Read-Host -Prompt "Application Pool Name"
[string]$AppPoolUser = Read-Host -Prompt "Application Pool Username Domain not required ex. PXML.Proxy$"
$Password = Read-Host -Prompt "Application Pool Account Password, try ` before $ in password"
$HostHeader = Read-Host -Prompt "Host Header Name"
# cmd /c C:\scripts\BaseIIS.cmd $WebServer $AppPool $AppPoolUser $Password $HostName
New-Item -path d:\Websites -itemtype directory
New-Item -path d:\Logs -itemtype directory
New-Item -path d:\Logs\$WebSite -itemtype directory
New-Item -path d:\websites\$WebSite -itemtype directory
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem in the input isn't the `dollar sign($)` but the starting `exclamation mark(!)`
You need to escape it with another one.

You password need to be inputed as: !!$Pass!123!!

[Read here to know more about this](https://connect.microsoft.com/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=195045&SiteID=99)

Why not using `get-credential` cmdlet:

```
$cred = Get-Credential -Message "Insert Username and Passsword"    
$cred.GetNetworkCredential().UserName
Jacob    
$cred.GetNetworkCredential().Password
!$Pass!123!!
```

or you can use:

```
$Password = Read-Host -Prompt "Application Pool Account Password" -assecurestring
[String]$Password = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto([Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($Password))
```

Comment: Definitely use `Get-Credential`.  This is why it exists.  `Read-Host` is not secure.

Answer (score 0):

this doesn't seem to be a problem with V3 :

```
PS>$t=Read-Host
!$Pass!123!!
PS>$t
!$Pass!123!!
```

Comment: You're right, the starting exclamation mark has this effect only if `-prompt` parameter have value.